# Threads on a multiprocessor system

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, multiprocessing, clone

Does the clone() function take advantage of a multiprocessor system?

I mean, if I create many threads inside a main process using the clone() function, will these created threads be executed on different processors simultaneously?

thanks

Comment: `clone` is not a Posix function.

Answer (score 1):

You don't generally have control over processors from user space (with some exceptions). It is the kernel's decision how to distribute all the separate execution contexts onto the available hardware processors. It will probably try to be nice and smart (i.e. a sleeping thread is woken up on the same CPU where it went to sleep, and if there are is no contention, separate threads should spread out over available CPUs), but a real operating system running many processes is a complex thing and the choice of processor depends on many factors.

Comment: so if I create many threads with clone, they might be distributed on many processors?

Comment: Yes, they might. But it's *really* confusing and pointless to think about `clone`. You're not meant to use or know about `clone`.